# Como puedo un parámetro desde mi controlador al succes del Ajax para redireccionar a otro View

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net, mvc, entity-framework

quisiera que me ayudaran con el siguiente problema:

tengo este código en mi view:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("Insert", "Cotizacion")",

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(cotizacion),
            traditional: true,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                **window.location.href = response.newUrl;**
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

dónde tengo que retornar un parámetro Id desde mi controlador, puesto que necesito que al darle clic al botón guardar me lleve directamente a la vista editar, por lo que necesito el Id de la cotización creada recientemente...

Cómo podría enviar ese parámetro desde el controlador al succes del ajax para poder viajar a la otra vista?

Este es mi controlador:

```
public ActionResult Insert(Cotizaciones model)
        {
            {
               var rh = _cotizacionService.Insert(model);
                if (rh.Response)
                {
                    CotizacionesProducto c = new CotizacionesProducto();

                    for (int i = 0; i < listaProductos.Count; i++)
                    {
                        c.CotizacionesId = model.Id;
                        c.ProductoId = Convert.ToInt32(listaProductos[i]);

                        var rh2 = _cotizacionesproductoService.Insert(c);
                    }

                    return Json(new { newUrl = Url.Action("Edit", "Cotizacion")});
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: No se te olvide marcar la repsuesta como correcta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo le veo 2 posibles maneras.

1.-
Regresar la Url ya armada con tu id dentro de la propiedad newUrl de tu Json

```
return Json(new { newUrl = Url.Action("Edit", "Cotizacion", new { id = c.CotizacionesId }) });
```

2.-
Regresar una 2a propiedad de tu json con el id

```
return Json(new { newUrl = Url.Action("Edit", "Cotizacion"),id = c.CotizacionesId });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo!!! me funcionó perfectamente!!!