# Enviar json a controlador y abrir nueva view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Estoy intentando realizar un envío de datos a otra vista, lo que hacia hasta el momento era pasarle el json por url pero me ha saltado un error en el cual me decía que tenia demasiados parametros, al ser dinámico pueden ser `n`, en la vista tenia una función que pasaba lo datos y los reconvertia, después con una llamada el `iframe` le pasaba por url los datos de la siguiente manera:

Vista:

```
    function CrearModelo(data) {

       var json = JSON.stringify(data);

       //metodo para enviar al controlador el json y convertirlo a un objeto multidimensional
       mvc.Configuracion.CrearOperacion.post({ Json: json }, res => {

            //Manejador de iframes
            pestanas.verOpcion(11);
            //posicionar el iframe en el top y llamar al controlador enviandole el json
            top.frames['FrMnuCfgPuestosTrabajo'].location.href = '/Configuracion/EmularLocal?Json=' + res;
            pestanas.anadirEvento();

        });             
    }
```

Controlador:

```
[TsVisible]
public ActionResult EmularLocal(string Json)
{
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Modelo>>(Json);
    return View("EmuladorLocal", new EmularXaml() { Listado = result });
}
```

Funciona si el json es pequeño, pero estoy buscando la manera de generar el modelo sin tener que pasarselo por url.

**¿Cómo podría hacerlo?**

---

## EDICIÓN

He logrado enviarme los datos a traves de `localstorage` pero al momento de ejecutar la visualización me salta un nuevo error:

> **HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found**
>
> El módulo Solicitar filtrado está configurado para denegar una solicitud cuando la cadena de consulta sea demasiado larga.

El nuevo código usado es:

Vista_Uno:

```
function CrearModelo(data) {

    var json = JSON.stringify(data);

    mvc.Configuracion.CrearOperacion.post({ Json: json }, res => {                  

        localStorage.setItem("json",res);
        pestanas.verOpcion(11);
        top.frames['FrMnuCfgPuestosTrabajo'].location.href = '/Configuracion/EmularLocal'
        pestanas.anadirEvento();

    });             
}
```

Genero el Json y lo guardo en `localstorage`, después cargo el iframe.

Controller:

```
[TsVisible]
public ActionResult EmularLocal()
{           
    return View("EmuladorLocal");
}
```

Cargo la vista.

Vista_Dos:

```
@model EmularXaml
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EmuladorLocal";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Comun.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="content" class="espacio-arriba">

        <div id="accordion" class="accordion">

        </div>      
    </div>

}
@section pagespecific {

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var datos = localStorage.getItem("json");
        localStorage.clear();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: "/Configuracion/GetJsonEmular/",
            data: { "Json": datos},
            success: function (data) {
                $('#accordion').html(data);
            }
        });                     
    });
</script>
```

Cargo los datos en una variable y le paso por Ajax los datos, pero me salta que la url es demasiado larga con el **Error 404.15**.

Controlador:

```
[HttpGet]
[TsVisible]
public ActionResult GetJsonEmular(string Json)
{
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Modelo>>(Json);
    return PartialView("_Modelo", new EmularXaml() { Listado = result });           
}
```

Recojo el Json y lo deserializo, devuelvo una vista parcial con el modelo deseado.

Cuando son pocos datos va a la perfección, pero cuando es grande me salta el limitador, he buscado como solucionarlo pero añadir al `web.config`

```
<httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536"/>
```

Y aumentar sus valores no me sirve, me sigue saltando, también he probado a cambiar la configuración del ISS, pero me resulta demasiado complejo e inseguro.

**¿Existe otra manera de enviarle los datos al controlador sin que sea por url?**

Comment: No lo puedes manejar como un objeto tu JSON desde el lado de C#? has probado usando fetch?

Comment: @vcasas lo que quiero es eliminar el uso de las url, usar las herramientas propias de asp, pero ese json, no se guarda en un archivo, es una variable que se transforma en el controlador, entonces, creo, ya que desconozco el uso de fetch, no me serviría correctamente, he probado sin resultados con: Ajax, cookies y localstorage

Comment: de donde sale `mvc.Configuracion.CrearOperacion.post` ? eso es codigo javascript o .net, porque no entiendo si lo ejecutas del lado del browser o del servidor

Comment: porque tienes que usar un frame para realizar un post, en realidad no entiendo dodne ejecuta ese codigo, porque hay formas mucho mejores de invocar un action

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Es código javascript, es básicamente un ajax, hace una llamada al controlador y le envia los parametros, mi web está realizada en iframes, ya que es una webapp y dispone de varias pestañas por las que navegar y realizar tareas, que otras maneras existen para invocar un action?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que buscas es algo parecido a esto.

MVC mapea tu json directamento a un modelo que ya tengas en tus parametros.
Solamente crea un modelo, y lo especificas como parametro para que en tu controller lo traiga mapeado.

```
public class MiModelo
{

 public int Id{get;set;}

 public string Descripcion {get;set;}

}

[TsVisible]
public JsonResult EmularLocal(MiModelo model)
{

  return Json(new { newUrl = Url.Action("EditAction", "Controller", new { id = model.Id }) });
}
```

Luego sigues lo de la sig contestacion:

[Como puedo un parámetro desde mi controlador al succes del Ajax para redireccionar a otro View](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/285094/como-puedo-un-par%c3%a1metro-desde-mi-controlador-al-succes-del-ajax-para-redireccion/285153#285153)

Comment: Mi principal problema es el iframe, porque la llamada que tengo es `top.frames['FrMnuCfgPuestosTrabajo'].location.href` y no se como podría llamar al iframe pasandole el json sin pasarselo por url, intentaré transformarlo a tu manera a ver si me sirve

Comment: He intentado con tu manera, pero no he sido capaz de solucionar mi error, he editado la pregunta añadiendo mas datos y actualizado la situación